# Design pattern for reusing common code with slightly varying logic

Tags: design-patterns

I have 3 classes. All classes are very similar but their implementation slightly differs.

```
class StrategyA {
  double do() {
    double d = method1();
    method2();
    return method3(d);
  }
}

class StrategyB {
  double do() {
    double d = method1();
    method2();
    return method4(d);
  }
}

class StrategyC {
  double do() {
    double d = method1();
    method3();
    return method4(d);
  }
}
```

All classes are very similar, most of the logic is the same, but at the end of implementation all classes have slightly different return method. This is only example with single method, there are much more duplicate logic.

How to reduce this implementation to avoid duplication?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Tempalte Method Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) seems like a good fit for this use case :

```
abstract class AbstractStrategy {
    public final double do() {
        double d = method1();
        return doMoreWork(d);
    }
    
    protected abstract Double doMoreWork(Double d);

    protected double method1() { return Double.valueOf(1.0d); }
    protected void method2() { //do something }
    protected double method3(Double d) { return Double.valueOf(d); }
    protected double method4(Double d) { return Double.valueOf(d/10); }

}

class StrategyA extends AbstractStrategy {
  double doMoreWork(Double d) {
    method2();
    return method3(d);
  }
}

class StrategyB extends AbstractStrategy {
  double doMoreWork(Double d) {
    method2();
    return method4(d);
  }
}

class StrategyC extends AbstractStrategy {
  double doMoreWork(Double d) {
    method3();
    return method4(d);
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh yes, this one seems great. Thanks!